# Arduino: can't return dereferenced pointer value from library function to sketch

Tags: c++, arduino, libraries

I'm having some trouble with a library I recently wrote. I have this char pointer as one of my private variables which is giving me some problems. Below is my .h file -[image]

I use this **_dateTime** variable in the **return_datetime()** public function like so-

[image]

Now, when I run my sketch with this library I get an error. This is what it looks like:

[image]

What's going on here? I thought private variables like **_dateTime** that I created could be used by all the public functions. Correct?

Comment: Hey I figured out what the problem was. I hadn't placed the LibraryName:: in front of my function return_datetime(). Now it works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to split declaration and definition of member functions, you should specify the class, when you are defining the function:

```
char CalcTime::return_datetime()
//   ^^^^^^^^
```